# Controller tests error message: "ActionView::Template::Error: The asset "MyString" is not present in the asset pipeline"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5

This is code of test that is failing:

```
  test "should get index" do
    get products_url
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Error info is ActionView::Template::Error: The asset "MyString" is not present in the asset pipeline.

WTF?

Comment: Just read that mentioned test on controller is called functional, not unit, unit is for models.

Comment: Just followed hint from error info, if removed from view template: <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %> then test passes with no error. – Bartosz Wais 11 mins ago

Comment: After another 5 minutes thinking, it looks like "MyString" is property from fixtures.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem but found a simple solution.
First I fixed in /test/fixtures/products.yml

```
one:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: lorem.jpg
  price: 9.99

two:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: lorem.jpg
  price: 9.99
```

Lastly I **actually added into my assets/images an image titled "lorem.jpg"**. I found it confusing since they don't mention this at all on the book but hopefully this little pointer it will get you back on track.

Comment: You likely ran `bin/rails test` by mistake whereas the book says to run `bin/rails test:models`. Later in the chapter they discuss this very error and how to resolve it. For those interested the book is: Agile Web Development with Rails

Comment: @MichaelMinton Nice catch, I had the same problem. The book doesn't mention it briefly :) .

Answer (score 1):

you must make sure images in fixtures exists .    [look here](http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot-226-51/section-8.4.html)